# Access violation in C++ polymorphism (virtual pointer function pointing to wrong place?)

Tags: c++, inheritance, polymorphism, access-violation

This is getting weird. Ship inherits from Entity and MerchantShip from Ship, other types are to be added later, but the basic idea, and what is asked by the professor, is that I use polymorphism, so that I can work on a collection of the main class (pointer with allocated memory used as an array in my implementation), thus there is a virtual void update in all three of the later classes. In fact I have used all combinations of virtual and non-virtual functions that could make sense. Code:

```
#include "stdafx.h"
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;


class Entity
{
public:
    int x, y;
    virtual void update() = 0;
    void print()
    {
        cout << "x:" << x << ", y:" << y << endl;
    }
};

class Ship: public Entity
{
public:
    virtual void update()
    {
        Move();
    }

    void Move(){x++;};
};

class MerchantShip: public Ship
{
public:
    void update()
    {
        DontMove();
    }

    void DontMove(){};
};

int main(int argc, char* argv[])
{
    int EntityNumber = 2;
    Entity* entities;
    entities = (Entity*)malloc(EntityNumber*sizeof(Entity));
    for (int i = 0; i < EntityNumber; i++)
    {
        entities[i].print();
        entities[i].update();
        entities[i].print();
        cout << endl << "next ship: " << endl;
    }
    system("PAUSE");
    return 0;
}
```

Ok, so it compiles great (stdafx.h is only needed in Visual Studio) but I get a runtime error, which is an access violation at 0xffffffffffffffff when it tries to get into the overridden update functions. In the debug information it consistently looks like the virtual function pointer (__vfptr) is pointing clearly elsewhere than where it should be (0xcdcdcdcdcdcdcdcd), and it's always the same location, even in another code I tried to do the same thing.

Research so far:
cause #1 (does not apply): uses function in a DLL that was freed before being called
cause #2 (again does not apply): programmer forgets to inherit.
I have not come across any other issue in any threads with the same problem, and I've been debugging for a couple of days. If I remove override it will just call the Base class's function.
Any clues?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Segfault when calling virtual function of derived class](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15888851/segfault-when-calling-virtual-function-of-derived-class)

Comment: Side note: Have `virtual` destructors for abstract classes and derived.

Comment: How do they differentiate from normal destructors?

Comment: @user3079666 When you delete an object through a pointer to the base class, in your case e.g. `delete entities[0]`, a virtual destructor ensures that the destructor of the dynamic type is called and not only the base-class destructor. This prevents resource-leaks.

Comment: Good point, I had not foreseen that.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You should not use `malloc` to allocate C++ object. `new` is the correct operator for this.

You will not be able to instantiate `Entity` as it is an abstract class.

What you need is an array of pointers to `Entity` and associate to them address of concrete `Entity` (`Ship` or `MerchantShip`), like this:

```
typedef Entity *PEntity;
PEntity entities[2];
entities[0] = new Ship();
entities[1] = new MerchantShip();
```

Then polymorphism will apply correctly when you will call virtual method via pointers:

```
for (int i=0; i<2; i++) {
  entities[i]->print();
  entities[i]->update();
  entities[i]->print();
}
```

What is really important is to understand that there is no `Entity` here, just specific `Entity`. `Entity` is just a concept; `Ship` (or `MerchantShip`) is one of its concrete realization. You can manipulate concrete objects via their abstract interface.

Comment: The "new" keyword did the trick, thanks a million, wouldn't have thought of it!

Comment: @user3079666 - check also `placement new`, for cases where you need to use a pre-allocated memory pool for a C++ class

Comment: @user3079666 std::vector is a better way to use dynamic arrays. And use RAII for resource-management to prevent memory leaks. As a general rule, try to use new manually and wrap every resource (memory, file, mutex ...) in a RAII class.

Comment: @user3079666 it is rarely used, but can offer significant advantages in some cases. Also `placement new` is a case where you manually need to call destructors.

Comment: @ddriver I don't think a beginner should bother with placement new. Instead, learning to use std::vector and RAII correctly should have priority.

Comment: @Jens - I don't tell him to bother with it, just to know it is there in case some day he needs it. That's why I just added a comment and did not post an answer based on it, since it is not what he needs in his particular case.

Comment: Thank you for the suggestions, I'm also looking into RAII, as for vector, I kind of like it more when I work on a lower level so I'll learn to use it but I'll still stick to malloc and new, out of masochism :P All suggestions are welcome and will inevitably be studied, which will be used comes down to preference, style, and possibly my own stupidity if I choose something that is both hard and inefficient.

Comment: @user3079666 Using RAII is not only about masochism. If you do not use it, it will be very hard to write correct (non-resource-leaking) code when exceptions are involved. In some cases, it is not even possible to do it. Consider a function taking `int*, int` and the following call `f( new A(), can_throw() )`. Now, if `can_throw` throws an exception, it  is possible that the memory for A has been allocated, but it will not be released. In summary, writing correct code without RAII is not possible or you have to restrict C++ seriously.

Comment: @Jens, I was referring to using pointers and malloc() as masochism, instead of just using vectors, RAII is something I intend to look at as soon as I am free of the semester's projects and exams, maybe sooner still (if the rest of the project goes without much need of debugging). I'm just saying that I'm going to program as I feel more comfortable, to prevent other people from telling me to take a completely different direction to the one I'm taking - not that I will not look into it of course. As I see it, RAII can be used without changing too much my general direction.

Comment: @user3079666 It's good to learn as your comfortable, but I think it is a good way to learn a good way from the start. I see a lot of really bad code written by people who started with C and then learned C++ by learning one step at a time to improve their C code with classes. I think that the C-part should be ommitted and the C++ should be taught in the beginning, std::vector instead of plain arrays. Btw, std::vector is also a form of RAII :-)

Comment: @Jens It's just a dream, you canoot make things correct at the beginning there is a lot of things to learn before being able to do the right thing (if such a thing exists). Everybody need to begin with simple things and then complexify... RAII is not easy as you think for example. Same for placement new, it adds unecessary complexity for a beginner, he has to focus on something else first.

Comment: I have tried to write tutorials so I can understand the basics better, I do agree that some things are best taught early, but sometimes by doing that teachers omit some very useful things. I went through C because of the university and I loved how I was responsible for every little access violation I caused, it's a great challenge, and you feel like you really know what's going on. I do not reject anything at all, and I love reading about efficient programming, but when people reject your code and tell you to use something else, you just don't wanna do it the other way.

Comment: @Jean-BaptisteYunès It's not as dreamy as you think. There are really good introductory books which introduce vector before manual arrays, string before `char*`, iterators and algorithms before pointers. Look at https://isocpp.org/tour for an example, or Andrew Koenig's Accelerated C++. In fact, this is how I would seperate good C++ book from the not so good ones.

Answer (score 1):

`malloc` does not create and initialize an object but just reserves a block of memory. In C++, you should stay away from manually allocated dynamic arrays and use `std::vector` instead

```
#include "stdafx.h"
// these headers are discouraged. Use cstdlib and cstdio instead.
//#include <stdlib.h> 
//#include <stdio.h>

#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
#include <memory>

using namespace std;


class Entity
{
public:
    int x, y;
    virtual void update() = 0;
    void print()
    {
        cout << "x:" << x << ", y:" << y << endl;
    }

    virtual ~Entity() {} // any base-class should have this
};

class Ship: public Entity
{
public:
    virtual void update()
    {
        Move();
    }

    void Move(){x++;};
};

class MerchantShip: public Ship
{
public:
    void update()
    {
        DontMove();
    }

    void DontMove(){};
};

int main(int argc, char* argv[])
{
    int EntityNumber = 2;
    std::vector<std::unique_ptr<Entity>> entities(EntityNumber);

    // the array is empty so you have to create some objects in it
    entities[0] = new MerchantShip;
    entities[1] = new Ship;

    for (int i = 0; i < EntityNumber; i++)
    {
        entities[i].print();
        entities[i].update();
        entities[i].print();
        cout << endl << "next ship: " << endl;
    }

    system("PAUSE");
    return 0;
}
```

I have also added a virtual destructor to your base class.